# Is this right way to solve the array partition problem?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, algorithm

I have problem presented to me by leetcode.com

Problem statement:

Given an array of 2n integers, your task is to group these integers into n pairs of integer, say (a1, b1), (a2, b2), ..., (an, bn) which makes sum of min(ai, bi) for all i from 1 to n as large as possible.

Example 1:
Input: [1,4,3,2]

Output: 4 
Explanation: n is 2, and the maximum sum of pairs is 4 = min(1, 2) + min(3, 4).

Note:
n is a positive integer, which is in the range of [1, 10000].
All the integers in the array will be in the range of [-10000, 10000].

I have attempted to solve this using below javascript code

```
// NOTE: This is more optimal and can work
function chunkWithoutIndex(inputArr, partition) {
  let length = inputArr.length;
  let sliced = [];
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
    let subArr = sliced[count];
    if (!subArr) {
      sliced[count] = [];
    }
    let subArrLen = sliced[count].length;
    if (subArrLen !== partition) {
      sliced[count].push(inputArr[i]);
    } else {
      count++;
      sliced[count] = [inputArr[i]]
    }
  }
  return sliced;
}

// NOTE: This does not consider the chunk size
function checkWithTwoPointers(inputArr) {
  let length = inputArr.length;
  let left = 0;
  let right = length - 1;
  let sliced = [];
  while (left <= right) {
    if (left !== right) {
      sliced.push([inputArr[left], inputArr[right]]);
    } else {
      sliced.push([inputArr[left] || inputArr[right]]);
    }
    left++;
    right--;
  }
  return sliced;
}

function arrayPartition(inputArr, partition) {
  // let sliced = chunkWithoutIndex(inputArr, partition);
  let sliced = checkWithTwoPointers(inputArr);
  let sum = 0;
  let slicedLen = sliced.length;
  for (let i = 0; i <= slicedLen - 1; i++) {
    sum = sum + Math.min(...sliced[i]);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

While submitting the problem for acceptance, i get failures due to different test cases.

See the test case runs fine for input = [1, 4, 3, 2] which is expecting the output of 4.
So pairing would be

```
(1, 4) , (3, 2) = 1 + 2 = 3
(1, 3), (4, 2) = 1 + 2 = 3
(1, 2), (4, 3) = 1 + 3 = 4 --> Selected Pair
```

There is another test case input = [1, 1, 2, 2] , it is expecting the output to be 3?

If i use the same function written above it would create a pair of (1,2) , (1, 2) => 1+ 1 = 2. But they are expecting this pair now (1,1), (2, 2) => 1 + 2 = 3.

How to solve this problem ? Am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to first sort the array, and then take the sum of every number with an even index (i.e. the smallest number in each pair).

```js
var arrayPairSum = function(nums) {
    nums.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    let sum = 0;  

    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i += 2) {
        sum += nums[i];
    }

    return sum;
};
```

Tested on LeetCode:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The closest the numbers are, the less is lost when you take the minimum. Sort the array, and then chunk, and sum the minimums (the 1st item of each sub-array).

```js
const chunk = (size, arr) => Array.from(
  { length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) }, 
  (_, i) => arr.slice(size * i, size * (i + 1))
)

const sumMin = (size, arr) =>
  chunk(size, [...arr].sort())
  .reduce((s, [n]) => s + n, 0)
  
console.log(sumMin(2, [1, 2, 3, 4]));
console.log(sumMin(2, [1, 2, 1, 2]));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really learned the way for Array.from using length property.

Answer (score 2):

When you take minimum of the 2 numbers then larger number in the pair becomes irrelevant for us, so our target is to make sure every pair is as close as possible, which can be achieved though `sorting` and only adding element in even position.

```js
let arrSum = (arr) => arr.sort().filter((d, i) => i % 2 == 0).reduce((a, b) => a + b)


console.log(arrSum([1, 2, 3, 4]))
console.log(arrSum([1, 1, 2, 2]))
```